# strcpy was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, strcpy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char Buffer[20] = {'\0'};

    cout << "Enter a line of text: " << endl;
    string LineEntered;
    getline (cin, LineEntered);

    if ( LineEntered.length() < 20 ){
        strcpy(Buffer, LineEntered.c_str()); // This strcpy. is not declared in scope for some reason.
        cout << "Buffer contains: " << Buffer << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
main.cpp:14:43: error: 'strcpy' was not declared in this scope
```

Why is it having this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `strcpy` function is in the include file `string.h`. So add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Or, alternatively if you want to be more C++ about it,

```
#include <cstring>
```

and use `std::strcpy()`.

Comment: "if you want to be more C++ about it" — ___or___ if you don't want to use deprecated headers.